Using mediainfo.js in Blazor Webassambly
I am trying to use mediainfo.js in my Blazor Webassambly App.
Using JS in this context is new to me, so I am not shure how to deal with this.
Calling javascript functions out of my c# code is not the problem, but if I try to use some mediainfo part inside of my own javascript function, I get errors.
I tried different ways to import the madiainfo.js library to may project: as File, over CDN,...
But every time it seems that it could not be found if I try to use it.
Maybe someone can give me a small example how to use it.
regards
Alex
UPDATE:
Here is what I am doning at the moment:
at index.html I have this lines:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediainfo.js/dist/mediainfo.js"></script>
<script src="mediainfo-wrapper.js"></script>

my mediainfo-wrapper.js is this:
async function getMediaInfo(file) {
    const mediaInfoInstance = await MediaInfo({ format: 'object' });
    const fileData = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const result = await mediaInfoInstance.analyzeData(() => file.size, () => fileData);
    return result;
}

and with this line I call the JS function from my Blazor code:
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getMediaInfo", file);

After some more experiments, there is still no solution, but I think my problem is, that I not know how to correctly import the needed js files/modules. In the npm package there are different subfolders (esm, esm-bundle, umd) I tried all of them as entry point, but I am not shure what is the right way for my Blazor Webassambly, or even if it is possible at all.
I would be very happy to get some help, because I have no more ideas what I can try here.

You might want to check out How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Following these guidelines can significantly improve your chances of getting help.

Hi buzz, I added one way I have tried. There are several more versions with minor or big differences, but all of them lead to the same result: It did no work ;-)
